# Page loads on calling javascript function

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a DIV tag which is hidden in a aspx page, on click of a button a javascript method in the page is called which invokes the hiddden div. The javascript method is invoked successfully but after it executes the page loads and does the method functionality doesn work.

```
<wcl:Button ID="xyz" runat="server" CssClass="button" Text="Add" Width="90px" Height="18px" 
            OnClientClick="return ABC(); return false;" EnableAJAX="True"/>
```

Comment: please post your code

Comment: <wcl:Button ID="xyz" runat="server" CssClass="button" Text="Add" Width="90px" Height="18px" OnClientClick="return ABC(); return false;" EnableAJAX="True"/> </td> On Clicking this method the abc method is called.

Comment: I had put two alert messages at the start and end of the javascript method. in between these two alerts im able to see the POPUP as code given in the function code.

Comment: @user2586782 what is `wcl`, you use custom controls? can you provide js code also?

Comment: please share `ABC()` method code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved, i was used return false at the end of the javascript method and it worked.

Thanks